# WPF: Multiple pages, each page has its own context menu, how to set global menu?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a window that displays different Pages. Each page has one or more Context menus. I would like main window to display these context menues in the main app menu. So, if one page listview with context menu that has Delete and Copy, main app menu should have menu "Commands" with commands Delete and Copy. When page changes, Commands menu should change to whatever context menu new page is using.

Context menus have commands defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a shared collection of the items you want to show, and then databind to that item -- the main window can bind to the property, as can the context menu. You can likely use the same data template for both.